# Create regex object using string input

Tags: javascript, regex, angular, typescript

I have a regex when I instantiate the Regex object like this:

```
this.checkRegex = new RegExp(/^([0|\[+][0-9]{0,5})?([1-9][0-9]{0,15})$/);
```

It works fine, however If I store the regex in string it does not work:

```
  private checkReg: string = '/^([0|\[+][0-9]{0,5})?([1-9][0-9]{0,15})$/';
  this.checkRegex = new RegExp(this.checkReg);
```

I am using angular-typescript. What is the thing I am missing here when I am trying to instantiate by throwing string inside the constructor. Code sample will be really appreciated.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are passing a string to the RegExp constructor, you need to change it a little bit. Instead of

```
'/^([0|\[+][0-9]{0,5})?([1-9][0-9]{0,15})$/'
```

You would omit the preceding and trailing slash

```
'^([0|\\[+][0-9]{0,5})?([1-9][0-9]{0,15})$'
```

Note also double escaping the back slash.

Comment: It worked however I did not have to add double back slash. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store the RegExp as a String, store it without the forward slashes at the front and back. When creating the RegExp object, those get escaped:

```
new RegExp('/^([0|\[+][0-9]{0,5})?([1-9][0-9]{0,15})$/');
```

will result in

```
/\/^([0|[+][0-9]{0,5})?([1-9][0-9]{0,15})$\//
```

while,

```
new RegExp('^([0|\[+][0-9]{0,5})?([1-9][0-9]{0,15})$');
```

will work:

```
/^([0|[+][0-9]{0,5})?([1-9][0-9]{0,15})$/
```